# Python extract specific values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dictionary:

```
My_dict={'K0A1': 0.12, 'K1A1': 0.12, 'K2A1': 0.12, 'K3A1': 0.12, 'K0A2': 0.16, 'K1A2': 0.16, 'K2A2': 0.16, 'K3A2': 0.16, 'K0A3': 0.04, 'K1A3': 0.04, 'K2A3': 0.04, 'K3A3': 0.04, 'K0B1': 0.04, 'K1B1': 0.04, 'K2B1': 0.04, 'K3B1': 0.04, 'K0B2': 0.08, 'K1B2': 0.08, 'K2B2': 0.08, 'K3B2': 0.08, 'K0B3': 0.04, 'K1B3': 0.04, 'K2B3': 0.04, 'K3B3': 0.04, 'K0C1': 0.08, 'K1C1': 0.08, 'K2C1': 0.08, 'K3C1': 0.08, 'K0C2': 0.04, 'K1C2': 0.04, 'K2C2': 0.04, 'K3C2': 0.04, 'K0C3': 0.04, 'K1C3': 0.04, 'K2C3': 0.04, 'K3C3': 0.04, 'K0D1': 0.08, 'K1D1': 0.08, 'K2D1': 0.08, 'K3D1': 0.08, 'K0D2': 0.08, 'K1D2': 0.08, 'K2D2': 0.08, 'K3D2': 0.08, 'K0D3': 0.12, 'K1D3': 0.12, 'K2D3': 0.12, 'K3D3': 0.12}
```

I want to extract values of K0A1, K0A2,K0A3 in a separate list. Similary for K0B1,K0B2,K0B3 and so on until the end. How do I do it? Can anyone please suggest a solution

Comment: Umm... `My_dict["K0A1"]`?

Comment: Only K0A1, K0A2, K0A3 and so on, or also K1A1, K2A1 and so on in the same list?

Comment: I want to create another dictionary within the same dictionary grouping the above pattern of keys @E.Klahn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to group all subdictionnary by the second and third character of the key (you can actually use any other function if the logic is different), you could use a nested `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(dict))

for k,v in My_dict.items():
    d[k[1:3]][k] = v

out = {k: dict(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'0A': {'K0A1': 0.12, 'K0A2': 0.16, 'K0A3': 0.04},
 '1A': {'K1A1': 0.12, 'K1A2': 0.16, 'K1A3': 0.04},
 '2A': {'K2A1': 0.12, 'K2A2': 0.16, 'K2A3': 0.04},
 '3A': {'K3A1': 0.12, 'K3A2': 0.16, 'K3A3': 0.04},
 '0B': {'K0B1': 0.04, 'K0B2': 0.08, 'K0B3': 0.04},
 '1B': {'K1B1': 0.04, 'K1B2': 0.08, 'K1B3': 0.04},
 '2B': {'K2B1': 0.04, 'K2B2': 0.08, 'K2B3': 0.04},
 '3B': {'K3B1': 0.04, 'K3B2': 0.08, 'K3B3': 0.04},
 '0C': {'K0C1': 0.08, 'K0C2': 0.04, 'K0C3': 0.04},
 '1C': {'K1C1': 0.08, 'K1C2': 0.04, 'K1C3': 0.04},
 '2C': {'K2C1': 0.08, 'K2C2': 0.04, 'K2C3': 0.04},
 '3C': {'K3C1': 0.08, 'K3C2': 0.04, 'K3C3': 0.04},
 '0D': {'K0D1': 0.08, 'K0D2': 0.08, 'K0D3': 0.12},
 '1D': {'K1D1': 0.08, 'K1D2': 0.08, 'K1D3': 0.12},
 '2D': {'K2D1': 0.08, 'K2D2': 0.08, 'K2D3': 0.12},
 '3D': {'K3D1': 0.08, 'K3D2': 0.08, 'K3D3': 0.12}}
```

To access a single subgroup:

```py
out['0A']
# {'K0A1': 0.12, 'K0A2': 0.16, 'K0A3': 0.04}
```

###### Alternative output:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in My_dict.items():
    d[k[:3]].append(v)

out=dict(d)
```

Output:

```
{'K0A': [0.12, 0.16, 0.04],
 'K1A': [0.12, 0.16, 0.04],
 'K2A': [0.12, 0.16, 0.04],
 'K3A': [0.12, 0.16, 0.04],
 'K0B': [0.04, 0.08, 0.04],
 'K1B': [0.04, 0.08, 0.04],
 'K2B': [0.04, 0.08, 0.04],
 'K3B': [0.04, 0.08, 0.04],
 'K0C': [0.08, 0.04, 0.04],
 'K1C': [0.08, 0.04, 0.04],
 'K2C': [0.08, 0.04, 0.04],
 'K3C': [0.08, 0.04, 0.04],
 'K0D': [0.08, 0.08, 0.12],
 'K1D': [0.08, 0.08, 0.12],
 'K2D': [0.08, 0.08, 0.12],
 'K3D': [0.08, 0.08, 0.12]}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could just loop through the keys and store the ones you want. An example is below:

```
My_dict={'K0A1': 0.12, 'K1A1': 0.12, 'K2A1': 0.12, 'K3A1': 0.12, 'K0A2': 0.16, 'K1A2': 0.16, 'K2A2': 0.16, 'K3A2': 0.16, 'K0A3': 0.04, 'K1A3': 0.04, 'K2A3': 0.04, 'K3A3': 0.04, 'K0B1': 0.04, 'K1B1': 0.04, 'K2B1': 0.04, 'K3B1': 0.04, 'K0B2': 0.08, 'K1B2': 0.08, 'K2B2': 0.08, 'K3B2': 0.08, 'K0B3': 0.04, 'K1B3': 0.04, 'K2B3': 0.04, 'K3B3': 0.04, 'K0C1': 0.08, 'K1C1': 0.08, 'K2C1': 0.08, 'K3C1': 0.08, 'K0C2': 0.04, 'K1C2': 0.04, 'K2C2': 0.04, 'K3C2': 0.04, 'K0C3': 0.04, 'K1C3': 0.04, 'K2C3': 0.04, 'K3C3': 0.04, 'K0D1': 0.08, 'K1D1': 0.08, 'K2D1': 0.08, 'K3D1': 0.08, 'K0D2': 0.08, 'K1D2': 0.08, 'K2D2': 0.08, 'K3D2': 0.08, 'K0D3': 0.12, 'K1D3': 0.12, 'K2D3': 0.12, 'K3D3': 0.12}

values = []

for myKey in list(My_dict.keys()):
    if myKey[0:2] == 'K0' and (myKey[3] == '1' or myKey[3] == '2' or myKey[3] == '3'):
        if myKey[3] == '1':
            values.append([My_dict[myKey]])
        else:
            values[-1].append(My_dict[myKey])
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you only want the K0_1, K0_2, K0_3s, but it's easy to modify if you want something else.

Answer (score 1):

As 3 elements belong to the same category, you can sort the dictionary's keys and list the values of 3 consecutive elements and store them in a result dictionary, like this...

```py
from time import time

start = time()

Dict={'K0A1': 0.12, 'K1A1': 0.12, 'K2A1': 0.12, 'K3A1': 0.12, 'K0A2': 0.16, 'K1A2': 0.16, 'K2A2': 0.16, 'K3A2': 0.16, 'K0A3': 0.04, 'K1A3': 0.04, 'K2A3': 0.04, 'K3A3': 0.04, 'K0B1': 0.04, 'K1B1': 0.04, 'K2B1': 0.04, 'K3B1': 0.04, 'K0B2': 0.08, 'K1B2': 0.08, 'K2B2': 0.08, 'K3B2': 0.08, 'K0B3': 0.04, 'K1B3': 0.04, 'K2B3': 0.04, 'K3B3': 0.04, 'K0C1': 0.08, 'K1C1': 0.08, 'K2C1': 0.08, 'K3C1': 0.08, 'K0C2': 0.04, 'K1C2': 0.04, 'K2C2': 0.04, 'K3C2': 0.04, 'K0C3': 0.04, 'K1C3': 0.04, 'K2C3': 0.04, 'K3C3': 0.04, 'K0D1': 0.08, 'K1D1': 0.08, 'K2D1': 0.08, 'K3D1': 0.08, 'K0D2': 0.08, 'K1D2': 0.08, 'K2D2': 0.08, 'K3D2': 0.08, 'K0D3': 0.12, 'K1D3': 0.12, 'K2D3': 0.12, 'K3D3': 0.12}

sorted_keys = sorted(Dict)
res, ind = dict(), 0

while ind<len(Dict):
    temp = []

    for i in range(ind, ind+3):
        temp.append(Dict[sorted_keys[i]])
    else:
        res[sorted_keys[i][:3]] = temp
        ind += 3

print(res)

end = time()

print(f"\nTime Taken : {end-start}")
```

Output:-

```
{'K0A': [0.12, 0.16, 0.04], 'K0B': [0.04, 0.08, 0.04], 'K0C': [0.08, 0.04, 0.04], 'K0D': [0.08, 0.08, 0.12], 'K1A': [0.12, 0.16, 0.04], 'K1B': [0.04, 0.08, 0.04], 'K1C': [0.08, 0.04, 0.04], 'K1D': [0.08, 0.08, 0.12], 'K2A': [0.12, 0.16, 0.04], 'K2B': [0.04, 0.08, 0.04], 'K2C': [0.08, 0.04, 0.04], 'K2D': [0.08, 0.08, 0.12], 'K3A': [0.12, 0.16, 0.04], 'K3B': [0.04, 0.08, 0.04], 'K3C': [0.08, 0.04, 0.04], 'K3D': [0.08, 0.08, 0.12]}

Time Taken : 0.00011229515075683594
```